# Why is this basic react-beautiful-dnd example not animating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Research was fruitless, so hopefully I can find an answer here. All of this is being done on the latest node.js and create-react-app with react-beautiful-dnd installed. See images below code for examples of what is and should be happening.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

// fake data generator
const getItems = (count) => Array.from({length: count}, (v, k) => k).map(k => ({
  id: `item-${k}`,
  content: `item ${k}`
}));

// a little function to help us with reordering the result
const reorder =  (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
  const result = Array.from(list);
  const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
  result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

  return result;
};

// using some little inline style helpers to make the app look okay
const grid = 8;
const getItemStyle = (draggableStyle, isDragging) => ({
  // some basic styles to make the items look a bit nicer
  userSelect: 'none',
  padding: grid * 2,
  marginBottom: grid,

  // change background colour if dragging
  background: isDragging ? 'lightgreen' : 'grey',

  // styles we need to apply on draggables
  ...draggableStyle
});
const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver) => ({
  background: isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
  padding: grid,
  width: 250
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: getItems(10)
    }
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
  }

  onDragEnd (result) {
    // dropped outside the list
    if(!result.destination) {
      return;
    }

    const items = reorder(
      this.state.items,
      result.source.index,
      result.destination.index
    );

    this.setState({
      items
    });
  }

  // Normally you would want to split things out into separate components.
  // But in this example everything is just done in one place for simplicity
  render() {
    return (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
            >
              {this.state.items.map(item => (
                <Draggable
                  key={item.id}
                  draggableId={item.id}
                >
                  {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <div>
                      <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        style={getItemStyle(
                          provided.draggableStyle,
                          snapshot.isDragging
                        )}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      >
                        {item.content}
                      </div>
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    );
  }
}

// Put the thing into the DOM!
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>CodeForge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

What should be happening:

[image: react-beautiful-dnd working example]

What IS happening (Note: Cursor is hovering over list item 6 but screenshot doesn't show cursor):

[image: react-beautiful-dnd broken example]

Comment: What version of react-beautiful-dnd are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it may be that `provided.draggableStyle` should be `provided.draggableProps.style`. I hit that issue myself when I started experimenting with this library.